# How to redirect http to https for www and non www for a directory using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I'm trying to get all these conditions to redirect to https://www.domain.com/admin/  but only for a certain directory

```
RewriteCond
http://domain.com/admin/
http://www.domain.com/admin/
https://domain.com/admin/

RewriteRule
https://www.domain.com/admin/
```

I tried this but agave me a redirect loop:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/admin [R=301,L]
```

Thank you

UPDATE

I have a feeling that the vhost on the server has something to do with it. Here is what I have in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
  ServerName default.domain.com

  # Set application environment.
  SetEnvIf Host "^" APPLICATION_ENV=production
  SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^(stage\.)(.*)$" APPLICATION_ENV=staging BOGUS_HTTP_HOST=$2

  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteLogLevel 3

  # Remove parts from the front if host name has too many parts,
  # unless a directory with the right name exists in /var/www.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "^([^.]+)\.(.*[^.]+\.[^.]+)$"
  RewriteCond /var/www/%{HTTP_HOST} !-d
  RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "http://%2$1" [R,L]

  # Redirect admin and member requests to SSL connection
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin|member|join|order)(/.*)?$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1%2 [R,L]

  # Set the bogus ssl header
  SetEnv BOGUS_HTTPS "off"

  UseCanonicalName Off
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have this rule in `/admin/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: That gives a redirect loop.

Comment: There or no looping in this rule but you may have some rule or code redirecting back to http:// Are you using some framework here? Test it in chrome Dev tool to see what 301/302 redirects you get.

Comment: I updated my original question with what I found on the server vhost  file that might be interfering with the redirect.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmm that's right. Comment out 3 lines below **`# unless a directory with the right name exists in /var/www.`** and restart your Apache. Then test in Chrome dev tool to test it out.